# Skype Button: How to prevent vertical space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started learning HTML, CSS and JS. I am trying to add Skype button to my web, but it creates blank lines above and below. How do I remove those blank lines and make Skype button appear inline with text coded before Skype button code? (Sorry, I am very new to stackoverflow, so not able to post image of my result.

This is the sample code I am trying with.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960-Grid-System-master/code/css/960_12_col.css" />
    <div class="container_12 clearfix">
    <div class="grid_12">
    <span>Contact XXXXXXX XXXXX</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Call_xxxxxxx_1">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "call",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call_xxxxxxx_1",
          "participants": ["xxxxxxx"],
          "imageSize": 32
        });
      </script>
    </div>
    <p>footer</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The skype button api creates a paragraph

```
<p id="SkypeButton_Call_xxxxxxx_1_paraElement" style="font-size:30px; color:#444444">...</p>
```

Which causes your spacing issue. To get around this you can insert some js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = document.createTextNode("Contact XXXXXXX XXXXX");
    document.getElementById("SkypeButton_Call_xxxxxxx_1_paraElement").insertBefore(text, document.getElementById("SkypeButton_Call_xxxxxxx_1_paraElement").firstChild);
 </script>
```

To your call to add your text to the generated paragraph.

Comment: Thanks lowky. I am getting >>>Contact XXXXXXX XXXXX<<< and skype button in one line based on your code, but it still creates blank line above and below it. May be I still don't have enough knowledge to understand all this to work as I am just learning. I will read more on JS and try to work on this.